# how to return only the selected columns in a to_jsonb call?

Tags: postgresql

I have a table and would like to only output the `id` and `time` columns in json.

The table being:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "Session" (
  "id" UUID PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT gen_random_uuid(),
  "account_id" TEXT,
  "time" BIGINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 1000000 * extract(epoch FROM now())
);
```

This call outputs all the values:

```sql
WITH ret AS (
      INSERT INTO "Session" ("account_id")
        VALUES ('hello')
      RETURNING *
)
SELECT to_json(ret) FROM ret;

--  {"id":"516a3510-cff9-43fc-a178-363b5ea53f03","account_id":"hello","time":1613227250536862}
```

but I would like to only output the `id` and `time` columns. When I have this call, the column keys are changed to `"row"`

```sql
WITH ret AS (
      INSERT INTO "Session" ("account_id")
        VALUES ('hello')
      RETURNING (id, time)
)
SELECT to_json(ret) FROM ret;

-- {"row":{"f1":"c628c347-b273-4f72-9186-c14cd32a16f0","f2":1613227326917707}}
```

how do I output only this:

```sql
{"id":"516a3510-cff9-43fc-a178-363b5ea53f03", "time":1613227250536862}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to remove brackets from `RETURNING` like this:

```
WITH ret AS (
    INSERT INTO "Session" ("account_id")
        VALUES ('hello')
        RETURNING id, time
)
SELECT to_json(ret) FROM ret;
```

Answer (score 2):

By doing `(id, time)` you created a `ROW` constructor [Row](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ROW-CONSTRUCTORS) which does:

> The key word ROW is optional when there is more than one expression in the list.

> By default, the value created by a ROW expression is of an anonymous record type.

Hence:

`{"row":{"f1":"c628c347-b273-4f72-9186-c14cd32a16f0","f2":1613227326917707}}`

Do instead as @ErikMaruškin suggested:

`RETURNING id, time`